# WCF or Sockets for Communication in a real-time environment?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets, network-programming

I have a scenario where I need to send a series of data across 2 clients.

The data includes Serialized XML that will contain commands that the other client will need to react to.

I will also need to send images across the wire as I need to provide a chat facility in the form of video/audio chat.

I would like a single communication medium for both, as the number of messages/commands might be a few.

WCF or Sockets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF is API for building service oriented applications. I don't thing that Video/Voice chat is such kind of application.

First of all what transport features do you require for such application? My knowledge of Voice/Video transmission is very poor but I expect:

- Duplex communication where client connects to chat server, sends his voice/video data and receives voice/video data of other client.
- Streaming - the amount of data can be pretty big so it would be nice to work with data when you start to read them. Moreover some encoding algoritms are supposed to be used with streaming.
- Quality of service - controling sustainable pace of transmission. (If you want to make conference video chat you also need coordination of multiple streams)

So by simply describing these three expectations I already see the problem. WCF build-in Net.Tcp binding [does not allow duplex communication and streaming together](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/9b73383c-2db9-4db6-87b4-67833075783d/). Also be aware that performance of Net.tcp communication over WCF is much worse than plain socket communication. It is because WCF simplifies a lot of things but those simplification and generalizations slows processing.

Also based on selected algorithm [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594675/streaming-an-undetermined-number-of-objects-through-wcf) could be a problem.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightVoiceVideoChat.aspx) you can find some describtion of Video chat in Silverlight 4. Silverlight allows WCF and net.tcp binding but the communication is still developed on sockets.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) you can find description of widely used protocols for voice over IP - RTP for data transmission and RTCP for coordination and QoS. These protocols are also used for video transmission. By googling I found [implementation](http://www.streamcoders.com/products/rtpnet.html) for .NET (I don't know how good the implementation is, I just used google ...)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the things I would think about:

WCF might be useful if you anticipate several different kinds of client connecting to your server. Maybe in the future you might want to let other people write clients, more or less independent of you. On the other hand, if it's a closed system then you might prefer to write your own sockets code.

WCF gives you a higher-level abstraction, so presumably you can write your system more quickly. In particular, things like XML encoding and session management are not really part of your application domain and so you don't want to spend much time working on them. But higher abstraction typically involves a performance cost, because the abstraction layer is more general-purpose than any one application needs. With plain sockets you can tailor your system to your own needs, and that might allow for higher performance (at the cost of more fiddly development and bug-fixing.)

You might want to send your data/commands and video in separate streams. Presumably the data/commands must be sent over a reliable transport, but the video can suffer some loss. Or maybe the video should be sent with a high QOS whereas the data/commands can suffer latency. I've never actually used QOS and so I don't know what the issues are here, but it could impact your decision about WCF (either favourably or negatively.)

You can host your server in its own process or in IIS. If you host it yourself then you can do things your own way. I believe that WCF and IIS are good friends, so if you're thinking IIS then WCF might make life a lot easier. If you choose IIS (or any established web server) over your own host, you can take advantage of their infrastructure - scalability, reliability, encryption, and so on. The downside is that you might get locked into that server, but that might not be a problem in practice.

Depending on your environment you may be able to mix and match the various technologies and features. For example, we have a system that sounds vaguely similar to yours and we opted for: plain sockets in the client; plain sockets in the server but with an option to host the server in Apache instead; a custom XML library that does just what we need; embedded OpenSSL; COM at the core of the system but with dependencies on .NET. In particular, we used SOAP in our first prototype because its messaging and RPC was a perfect match for our design, but found it added too much complexity and replaced it with our own protocol.

If you have the time, then I suggest that you build a quick prototype in WCF and see what you think. Hope that it works out, but don't be afraid to dump it if it doesn't. The main principle is to deliver maximum business value to your customers as efficiently as possible, and that usually means that you should spend your efforts in your application domain rather than on infrastructure. But at the same time don't ignore secondary principles such as performance, reliability, scalability, maintenance, extensibility, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

WCF **or** Sockets??? These are not alternatives: WCF includes the NetTcpBinding and NetPeerTcpBinding, for TCP/IP communication.

If your clients are both Windows, you should use WCF.

Comment: Pieter's question is based on my comment to his previous question.